# C# ASP.NET retrieve DATE only issue from MS SQL 2014

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a Table A which contain Column A that having a data type of DATE. I've checked the records inside MSSQL, it was giving the correct result I want such as 16-Jun-2014.

But in my C# Razor Code, I tried to retrieve it with

```
    @foreach (var row in db.Query("SELECT * FROM Table_A"))
    {
        @row.Date
    }
```

In my website view, it is giving me 16-Jun-2014 12:00:00 AM.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Can't you format it? Like `@row.Date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` ?

Comment: So you don't want the time component of the date?

Comment: hi, @SonerGönül, I got it.. Thanks.
Was new to razor here, I've tried convert in sql query, I didn't knew that razor can do formatting when retrieving.

Comment: put the solution if you got it please don't leave as blank

Comment: if you are using mvc then best idea is place your sensitive information like database information inside a controller or inside data access layer class

Answer (score 2):

.NET has only `DateTime` type, which always includes both date and time. You have to format it the way you want it to be, for example

```
@row.Date.ToString("dd'-'MMM'-'yyyy");
```

You might need to set the desired culture also, if it's not correct by default. You can either set the application's culture, or provide the culture for this specific call

```
@row.Date.ToString("dd'-'MMM'-'yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Of course it's better to create the `CultureInfo` once and save it in a variable than to create it every time this is called.

Comment: I think would be better to use an _english-based_ `IFormatProvider` because `MMM` _might_ generate different results if OP's `CurrentCulture` is not an english-based one.

Comment: @SonerGönül Yes, that is what I'm referring to with the culture. I'll edit a bit

Answer (score 0):

```
@row.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

The code I use to display the DATE result only.
Thank you guys for helping.

Comment: It should be `MMM` not `MM`.

Comment: somebody already posted an answer for your question then no need to post same again by the questioner